# Como deixar textbox vazio depois de uma requisição Ajax via Post?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

tenho uma aplicação de cadastro em .net MVC e estou utilizando o Ajax para enviar os conteúdos dos Forms Para minha Action que cadastra, quando salvo o value dos campos, na minha view os values ainda ficam visíveis nos campos não deixando em branco ,como seria o padrão. Por favor verifiquem meu código:

```
    <div id="endereco">
    @Html.Label("Endereco: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.DescricaoEndereco, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Endereco", name = "Endereco" })

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Número: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Numero, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Numero" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Complemento: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Complemento, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Complemento" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Bairro: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Bairro, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Bairro", name = "Bairro" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Cidade: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Cidade, new { maxlength = "40", id = "Cidade", name = "Cidade" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("UF: ")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.UF, Model.UFList, new { id = "UF",name="UF" })
    <br />

<input type="button" value="Adicionar Endereco" onclick="adicionarEndereco()"/>
        <\div>
    function adicionarEndereco() {
    var codigoPessoa = $("#Pessoa").val();
    var cep = $("#Cep").val();
    var endereco = $("#Endereco").val();
    var numero = $("#Numero").val();
    var complemento = $("#Complemento").val();
    var bairro = $("#Bairro").val();
    var cidade = $("#Cidade").val();
    //var temp = document.getElementById("UF");
    var uf = $("#UF").val();  

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Master/CadastrarEndereco",
            data: {
                CodigoPessoa:codigoPessoa,
                Cep: cep,
                DescricaoEndereco:endereco,
                Numero: numero,
                Complemento: complemento,
                Bairro: bairro,
                Cidade: cidade,
                UF : uf,


            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#endereco").html(data);

            },


        });
}
          //Controller

                   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult CadastrarEndereco(SuperViewModel enderecoVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var endereco = Extentions.MapearEndereco(enderecoVM);
            EnderecoRepositorio.Cadastrar(endereco);
            EnderecoRepositorio.Commit();
        }
        var superVM = new SuperViewModel();
        superVM.UFList = Extentions.ObterUF();
        superVM.Enderecos = EnderecoRepositorio.ObterEnderecoPorPessoa(enderecoVM.CodigoPessoa);
        return PartialView("_EnderecoFields", superVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer uma função para limpar o form e chamar a mesma no `success` do ajax:

```
function limpaForm(){
    $("#Pessoa").val('');
    $("#Cep").val('');
    $("#Endereco").val('');
    $("#Numero").val('');
    $("#Complemento").val('');
    $("#Bairro").val('');
    $("#Cidade").val('');
    // Como UF é um dropdown, você precisa usar o change para ele mudar a view
    // Pelo que vi no código UF é seu id "default"
    $("#UF").val('UF').change();
}
```

Altere o `success` para:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#endereco").html(data);
    limpaForm();
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode adicionar isso no callback `success` da sua requisição ajax:

```
$('#Pessoa,#Cep,#Endereco,#Numero,#Complemento,#Bairro,#Cidade,#UF').val('');
```

Uma solução ideal seria você colocar esses campos dentro de um `form`. Facilita tanto na hora do envio quanto na hora de limpar os campos.

Ex.:

```
<form id="form_endereco" action="" method="post">
    @Html.Label("Endereco: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.DescricaoEndereco, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Endereco", name = "Endereco" })

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Número: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Numero, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Numero" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Complemento: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Complemento, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Complemento" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Bairro: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Bairro, new { maxlength = "50", id = "Bairro", name = "Bairro" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Cidade: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Cidade, new { maxlength = "40", id = "Cidade", name = "Cidade" })
    <br />
    @Html.Label("UF: ")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.UF, Model.UFList, new { id = "UF",name="UF" })
    <br />
</form>
```

E na sua função `adicionarEndereco()`:

```
function adicionarEndereco() {
    // pega automaticamente todos os valores preenchidos no form 
    // sem a necessidade de declarar uma variável pra cada um
    var dados = $('#form_endereco').serialize();

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Master/CadastrarEndereco",
            data: dados,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#endereco").html(data);

                // limpa todos os campos do form
                $('#form_endereco :input').val('');

            },
        });

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Mas e se ele tiver um `select` ou `textarea` também no formulário? `:input` não funcionaria.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters O selector `:input` seleciona todos os elementos dos tipos `input`, `textarea`, `select` e `button` dentro do formulário. [Documentação](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: Ah, sim! é verdade. Não é `input` e sim `:input`! Confudi! Mereceu +1, rsrsrsrsrs

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do luiz Henrique é bacana, mas sempre que podemos simplificar alguma coisa torna-mo-ás melhor

Você pode fazer isso em uma linha:

```
$('#meu-form').get(0).reset();
```

Dessa forma, se adicionar um `input` a mais no seu formulário, não vai precisar ter que adicionar ele em uma função.

Onde o `get(0)` pega o elemento do `DOM` guardado no `Array` gerado pelo `jQuery` e o `reset` é o método nativo do javascript para resetar formulários.

Vale lembrar que `reset` retorna o formulário para o estado inicial, ele não propriamente limpa um formulário. Se em estado incial um input tiver um valor igual a 5, quando resetar ele vai voltar a ter o valor igual a 5.

Você pode fazer assim no seu sucess:

```
success: function (data) {

        $('#meu-form').get(0).reset();
    },
```

Comment: Caso precise de uma forma mais tranquila para trabalhar com formulários ajax, pode usar o plugin que eu fiz para facilitar preenchimento e obtenção de dados. https://github.com/wallacemaxters/jquery-object-form

Comment: Valeu galera Obtive SUCESSO!!